# I can't install Scientific Linux CERN 5.7 on VMware 9 nor 8

Tags: linux

After installing VMware I use create the new virtual machine to install SLC 5.7.
I choose the installer disk image file(iso) which is the iso file of SLC 5.7 in one of my hard drives.
Continue a few more steps it asks me:

> What type of media contains the packages to be installed? Local CDROM
>   Hard drive
>   NFS Image
>   FTP 
>   HTTP

None of the choices works. Why VMware can't find the iso file?
I extracted the iso file and write it on DVD and use the installer disk but this error appears again. I tried everything comes to my mind, but still I can't install it.

Comment: If you try to install from DVD, you should not first extract it, but burn the iso without extraction.

Comment: I tried this too. iso file without extraction on DVD, but it didn't work,too.

Comment: Try to boot your Windows 8 CD in the VM (you don't have to do a full install) or any other CD/DVD that you know that works to make sure this is not a VMware install/config issue. Alternatively, reboot your machine with the burned ISO and make sure that it boots, to get the same result.

Comment: @Anthon: Thanks for your guide.I tried. It was not a VMware install/config issue. I reboot with the burned ISO and it doesn't boot. So how can I fix it?